# TypeError: Cannot read property 'childImageSharp' of null when using gatsby-image

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-image

I am trying to use Gatsby image but getting Cannot read property 'childImageSharp' of null. I can't find where is the error. Topsection.js is a under Component. the image.jpg is inside of src/images/images.jpg . Still getting the error.

Topsection.js

```
const TopSection = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    {
      featureimg: file(relativePath: { eq: "image.jpg" }) {
        childImageSharp {
          fluid(maxWidth: 60) {
            ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
          }
        }
      }
    }  
  `);
  

   return (
     <>
       <div className="first-post-thumbnail">
         <a href="/best-keyboard-for-wow/">      
           <Image fluid={data.featureimg.childImageSharp.fluid} />         
         </a>
       </div>
     </>
   );
 };

 export default TopSection;
```

### Error

```
     35 | <div className="first-post-thumbnail">
     36 |   <a href="/best-keyboard-for-wow/">
     37 |     
   > 38 |       <Image fluid={data.featureimg.childImageSharp.fluid} />
| ^  39 |   
     40 |   </a>
     41 | </div>
```

Config

```
/**
 * Configure your Gatsby site with this file.
 *
 * See: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/gatsby-config/
 */

module.exports = {
  /* Your site config here */
  siteMetadata: {
    title: ``,
    description: ``,
    author: ``,
  },
  plugins: [
  `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
  `gatsby-transformer-sharp`, `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,

  
  {

    
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },

    resolve: `gatsby-plugin-prefetch-google-fonts`,
    options: {
      fonts: [
        {
          family: `Poppins`,
          variants: [`200`,`300`,`400`,`500`,`600`,`700`, `900`]
        },
      ],
    },

    
  },
],
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Editors Note January 29, 2024: The answer below should be considered obsolete due to the gatsby-image package being deprecated. Only proceed if you are maintaining code or need a historical reference.*

*If you are building new, see replacement package:* https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-image/

*Original answer below this line.*

---

Assuming you've set your filesystem correctly and the image is available by GraphQL.

Try:

```
import Img from "gatsby-image"
// other imports

const TopSection = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
      query {
          featureimg: file(relativePath: { eq: "/images/image.jpg" }) {
              childImageSharp {
                  fluid(maxWidth: 60) {
                      ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  `);

  return <div className="first-post-thumbnail">
    <a href="/best-keyboard-for-wow/">
      <Img fluid={data.featureimg.childImageSharp.fluid} />
    </a>
  </div>;
};

export default TopSection;
```

The `relativePath` field of a file node is relative to the directory you specified in `gatsby-source-filesystem`.

I would suggest using `<Link>` component instead of native `<a>` (anchor) for internal navigation:

```
    <Link to="/best-keyboard-for-wow/">
```

Check the query in the GraphQL playground (`localhost:8000/___graphql`) to check the spelling and the results.

Comment: can you check the question again, i have added the config file.

Comment: On graphql i am getting the error of : "message": "Unknown fragment \"GatsbyImageSharpFluid\".",

Comment: No. It's giving me a error. Unknown fragment GatsbyImageSharpFluid

Comment: Do you have an image named `image.jpg`? Try removing the fragment and try getting the path or other parameters of the image, once the query is set, add the fragment.

Comment: Then your relative path should be `/images/image.jpg`. I've updated the answer. As I said, try retrieving other fields of the image before using directly the fragment in order to check your paths. If you can retrieve other fields from the image, your query will be correct.

Comment: Can you check the problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64810972/how-to-remove-hash-from-image-url-gatsby

Answer (score 0):

[Clearing the cache](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/build-caching/) was successful for me (in addition to removing package-lock.json and re-run npm install):

`gatsby clean`

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning the project and re-running the "npm install" works

```
npm run clean
```

then

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

The image should be placed in the **'static/images/image.jpg'** directory instead of **'src/images/image.jpg'**.